# can not install gimp

Tags: installation, package-management, gimp

I tried to install Gimp but I get an error that there are unmet dependencies.  How can I handle that.  I am running UBUNTU 12.04 in 64 bit.

This is the message I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gimp: Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.0-3 is to be installed
      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
      Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9 is to be installed
      Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.26.1-1 is to be installed
      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.10-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
      Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
      Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.36.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try install gimp using ppa

Open terminal and run this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing an application. It turned out I just needed to `sudo apt-get update`, otherwise it was trying to use old versions of dependencies... did you try that already?

Comment: I found using kernel 3.4 make Skype not stable. So im switching back to kernel 3.2 and everything goes fine :)